# How to auto-sum column and save to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

How can I auto-sum the "Total Hours" data in the tfoot and save to MySQL database and re-display in  same area? I've got two examples working, I would like to add the auto-sum functionality to the VizaHours web-app.

Working examples are here:

- http://onetimemobile.com/vizahours/index.php
- http://onetimemobile.com/autosummer

**EDITED 4-2-14 ADDED ALL CODE `index.php` below:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th> DAY </th>
    <th> DAY INFO </th>
    <th> HOURS </th>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td class="total-hours" colspan="2">TOTAL HRS &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;</td>
        <td><span>0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">BUD HOURS - START WEEK 3-24-14<br />unpaid</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM budsvizahours ORDER BY id DESC");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr class="record">
<td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?><br /><br /><a href="editform.php?id=<?php echo 
$row['id']; ?>"> Edit </a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED 4-2-14 ADDED ALL CODE `edit.php` below:**

```
<?php
// configuration
include('connect.php');

// new data
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$id = $_POST['memids'];
// query
$sql = "UPDATE budsvizahours 
    SET fname=?, lname=?, age=?
    WHERE id=?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($fname,$lname,$age,$id));
header("location: index.php");

?>
```

**EDITED 4-2-14 ADDED ALL CODE `editform.php` below:**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM budsvizahours WHERE id= :userid");
$result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="memids" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row['fname']; ?>" /><br>
Update Day Info<br>
<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row['lname']; ?>" /><br>
Hours This Day<br>
<input class="record" type="tel" name="age" value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>" />
<br><br>
<button class="edit-info-button" type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    }); 
}); 
function calculateSum() { 
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value); } 
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can only see a HTML table. Where is your PHP logic?

Comment: Thanks Raptor... new to posting here... All code but the MySQL connect.php page now. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//it work for your code...
//sum query is good but i case you don't want to do it by that way

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {


     var sum = cls_nm_tr = 0;//create variable to null or zero

        //making loop for your tr its depends on no of tr you have
        $('.record').each(function(i,e){


        var cls_nm_tr = $('td:eq(2)', this).html();//getting value from td
           sum =  parseInt(sum) +  parseInt(cls_nm_tr);//adding them in sum varible

                });//loops ends here

    console.log(sum);//here you got sum of HOURS.//"sum" variable have sum or hours

    //$(".yoru_footer_id").html(sum);//here you can put data in tfooter
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! :) Here is all of the code except the actual database connection PHP... Don't think you need that...?